# Moving my sidebars over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the most of my screen space and therefore, want to move my left and right side bars all the way over. (left all the way to the left and right all the way to the right) my site is [marikastravels.com](http://marikastravels.com).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Please do not add website links on questions. Instead try to give  relevant code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am new to web development and am only customizing a Wordpress theme. I don't know where the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to the WordPress admin and go to **Appearance** → **Editor**. Select `style.css` from the list on the right. Scroll down the bottom of the file and paste the following:

```
div#doc4 {
    min-width: 74.923em;
    width: 96%;
}
```

Click **Update File** and you should be good to go!